# Can I URL rewrite without redirecting on Apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

We have a rewrite rule that works fine, but the reason why we're rewriting is because the target URL is not so tidy.

```
foo.com/bar -> foo.com/some/really/long/address
```

What I would like to do is keep the `foo.com/bar` URL in the browser, but show the `foo.com/some/really/long/address` page. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Show your rewrite rules.

Answer (score 2):

mod_rewrite it what you need.

This is quite easy and its a powerfull tool.

I suggest to read this -> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

And example :

this estarts de rewriteengine, then applies some conditions and if they are true then applies the rewrite itself. its like a while/case codeblock.

The most helpful part is the log .;)

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteLogLevel 0
RewriteLog "/var/www/rewrite.log"

<Directory /var/www>

    Options -ExecCGI -Indexes
    AllowOverride none
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    #SetHandler none

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^(\w+.\w+)/(es|ca|en)/$ index.php?user=$1&lang=$2 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^(\w+.\w+)/$ index.php?user=$1&lang= [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^(\w+.\w+)/(\w+)?(/(.*))?$ index.php?user=$1&lang=$2$4 [L,QSA]
```

also, you can look at mod_proxy, it will do the trick but it's not the 'good way' in my opinion.

hope it helps.